# Fetching API data in Angular for fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, angular, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I have the function to return the api data for the user bills, and then mapped the data to conform to fullcalendar - when I console log the "this.calendarBills" its json format and the date is also formatted correctly, but when I set "events" for fullcalendar to this.calendarBills, it returns nothing on the calendar...

```
export class BillPageComponent implements OnInit {

  userId = localStorage.getItem('userId') || '';
  token = localStorage.getItem('token') || '';

  bills: Bill[] = [];
  calendarBills: [] = [];

  calendarOptions: CalendarOptions | undefined;

  constructor(
    public fetchApiData: FetchApiDataService,
    public snackBar: MatSnackBar,
    public dialog: MatDialog,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getBills(this.userId, this.token);
  }

  getBills(userId: string, token: string): void {
    this.fetchApiData.getBills(userId, token).subscribe((resp: any) => {
      this.bills = resp;
      this.calendarBills = resp.map((e: any) => ({ title: e.Description, date: e.Date }))
      console.log(this.bills);
      console.log(this.calendarBills);


      this.calendarOptions = {
        headerToolbar: {
          center: 'title',
        },
        initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
        eventSources: this.calendarBills,
        events: this.calendarBills, // alternatively, use the `events` setting to fetch from a feed
        weekends: true,
        editable: true,
        selectable: true,
        selectMirror: true,
        dayMaxEvents: true,
        dateClick: this.handleDateClick.bind(this),
        // select: this.handleDateSelect.bind(this),
        // eventClick: this.handleEventClick.bind(this),
        // eventsSet: this.handleEvents.bind(this)
        /* you can update a remote database when these fire:
        eventAdd:
        eventChange:
        eventRemove:
        */
      };
    })
  }
  handleDateClick(arg: { dateStr: string; }) {
    alert('date click! ' + arg.dateStr)
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

thanks for the help! Managed to find the problem - had to call the calendarOptions INSIDE the getBills. Also, big thanks to ADyson (those are the types of issues I have without realizing!)

```
getBills(userId: string, token: string): void {
    this.fetchApiData.getBills(userId, token).subscribe((resp: any) => {
      this.bills = resp;
      this.calendarBills = resp.map((e: any) => ({ title: e.Description, start: e.Date, allDay: true }));
      console.log(this.bills);
      console.log(this.calendarBills);
      // return this.calendarBills;

      this.calendarOptions = {
        headerToolbar: {
          center: 'title',
        },
        initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
        events: this.calendarBills, // alternatively, use the `events` setting to fetch from a feed
        weekends: true,
        editable: true,
        selectable: true,
        selectMirror: true,
        dayMaxEvents: true,
        dateClick: this.handleDateClick.bind(this),
        // select: this.handleDateSelect.bind(this),
        // eventClick: this.handleEventClick.bind(this),
        // eventsSet: this.handleEvents.bind(this)
        /* you can update a remote database when these fire:
        eventAdd:
        eventChange:
        eventRemove:
        */
      };
    })
  }
```

Comment: In the code you originally showed for the question, it's already inside the getBills... otherwise it's something I'd have probably noticed

Answer (score 0):

You said

> the date is also formatted correctly

...maybe so, but fullCalendar doesn't recognise or understand `date` as a property name of an event. It will not read it and use it as a date. Therefore, fullCalendar doesn't know where to place your event on the calendar, which is why you can't see it.

The names of the fields you can use in your events are clearly documented already at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-parsing. You need to specify `start` (for the start date/time of the event) and optionally also `end` (for the end date/time).

Assuming your date really is formatted correctly (as per https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-parsing) then

```
{ title: e.Description, start: e.Date }
```

should work for you.

Comment: it still isn't showing in the calendar - my event objects when console logged is : [
    {
        "title": "Electricity",
        "start": "2021-09-01"
    },
    {
        "title": "Phone Bill",
        "start": "2021-09-25"
    },
    {
        "title": "Internet Bill",
        "start": "2021-09-20"
    }
]

Comment: @gcy2312 try to add `allDay: true` to the object

Comment: still no change - console.log of calendarBills is : [
    {
        "title": "Electricity",
        "start": "2021-09-01",
        "allDay": true
    },
    {
        "title": "Phone Bill",
        "start": "2021-09-25",
        "allDay": true
    },
    {
        "title": "Internet Bill",
        "start": "2021-09-20",
        "allDay": true
    }
] but still nothing is showing up on the calendar

Comment: @gcy2312 I just noticed, `eventSources: this.calendarBills` makes no sense. You've got an array of events, not an event source object. Make sure to use `events: this.CalendarBills` only and remove the eventSource option from your code.. Setting the allDay flag won't make any difference in this situation, that's not useful advice - ShamPooSham has misunderstood how fullcalendar works

Comment: @gcy2312 also just to double-check, and hopefully this is stating the obvious, but all those events are in September. Currently it's October so you'll have to move the calendar back a month before anything will show... I only mention this because it has occasionally caught out previous askers on this site :-)

Comment: I have removed the eventSources completely (it was only there to test), but I still have no events showing in the calendar. It works fine in the console.log but won't transfer to the  calendarOptions

Comment: ADyson - thanks for the check - I did realize that, but it's still not showing the events